# access specific server behind reverse proxy

Tags: linux, reverse-proxy, http, redirect

I have multiple devices that are all behind a private network. I have a WAN facing server that I can call into. Is there any way for me to be able to send an HTTP request through the WAN server to a specific device behind the network? I have been looking at a reverse proxy and I think I am on the right track but as I have many devices that will be changing in and out I am not sure what the best way of doing that would be. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Why aren't you using IPv6?

Comment: The devices aren't connected to the WAN. I should have clarified that.

Comment: If they aren't connected to the network, how to you propose to reach them at all?

Comment: I was hoping to have some sort of redirect from the server that is connected to the network in order to delegate where each http request goes.

Comment: I think one of us has missed something. You simply cannot reach airgapped machines at all. A reverse proxy cannot help you with this. You will have to connect them to the network somehow before you can reach them by any method.

Comment: They are all on a private network but also on that private network is a server that is connected to the WAN. I was hoping to hit that server that is connected to the WAN and through it talk to the servers on it's private network.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reverse proxy to receive connections on a pre-defined port on the WAN interface and it will open new connections to the machines in the internal network (provided the WAN-connected server is dual-homed, that is, also has a connection to the internal network).

You could specify that TCP port 10000 will be forwarded to internal machine A, TCP port 10001 to machine B and so on.

For example, using a tool like [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html):

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:10000,fork TCP4:machineA,10000
socat TCP4-LISTEN:10001,fork TCP4:machineB,10000
socat TCP4-LISTEN:10002,fork TCP4:machineC,10000
...
```

You could also use HAProxy, nginx and any other reverse proxy server to do this. The internal machines will get TCP connections that terminate on the reverse proxy.